# Optimized argmin: an effective way to find an item minimizing a function

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, standard-library

Let us say I've got a collection of items and a score function on them:

```
struct Item { /* some data */ };
std::vector<Item> items;
double score(Item);
```

I'd like to find the item from that collection whose score is the lowest. An easy way to write this is:

```
const auto argmin = std::min_element(begin(items), end(items), [](Item a, Item b) {
    return score(a) < score(b);
});
```

But if `score` is a heavy-to-compute function, the fact that [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) actually calls it multiple times on some items may be worrying. And this is expected because the compiler cannot guess `score` is a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

How could I find `argmin` but with `score` being called only once per item? Memoization is one possibility, anything else?

My objective is to write a code snippet which is easy to read, in a dream world as obvious as calling `std::min_element` on the collection is.

Comment: You only need to store the most up to date minimal score, as far as I see it. Then you only need to call `score` once. Though it's kinda hackish, to be frank.

Comment: @StoryTeller I know how I could write a bunch of lines to do that, but I'd like to do it in a way allowing a quick reader to instantly understand what's going on.

Comment: you need to evaluate `score(item)` at least once for each item, so just do that and then find the minimum in the results (hope noone saw my completely confused previous comment ;)

Comment: If the vector is not too big, you can use `std::transform` to store all scores first, then apply `std::min_element`.

Comment: @liliscent It would find the minimum _score_, not the _item_ minimizing `score` ;)

Comment: But then `std::distance` from `begin` of the new vector to the `std::min_element` would give you an index which holds the item with the minimum score in the original `vector`

Comment: how about writing a function like in John Zwincks answer, then calling that function?

Comment: @YSC It will return you the index `i` of minimizer, thus `items[i]` is what you want.

Comment: @liliscent (a)Fureeish Yes that's right. It's worth an answer.

Comment: `the compiler cannot guess score is a pure function` what about C++14 `constexpr`?

Comment: @greybeard I have no idea. This is an interesting question, though its answer might be compiler-dependant: can a call to a `constexpr` pure function can be optimized away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested bu user @liliscent, one could:

1. generate a collection of precalculated scores,
2. find the minimum score from it,
3. and infer the position of the minimizing item from the position of the minimum score.

This is my reading of their suggestion:

```
template<class InputIt, class Scoring>
auto argmin(InputIt first, InputIt last, Scoring scoring)
{
    using score_type = typename std::result_of_t<Scoring(typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type)>;
    std::vector<score_type> scores(std::distance(first, last));
    std::transform(first, last, begin(scores), scoring);
    const auto scoremin = std::min_element(begin(scores), end(scores));
    return first + std::distance(begin(scores), scoremin);
}
```

With a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fb9102955d90397).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that does what you want--even going beyond the intuitive "call score exactly once per element" by realizing that there's nothing smaller than negative infinity!

```
const Item* smallest(const std::vector<Item>& items)
{
    double min_score = items.empty() ? NAN : INFINITY;
    const Item* min_item = items.empty() ? nullptr : &*begin(items);
    for (const auto& item : items) {
        double item_score = score(item);
        if (item_score < min_score) {
            min_score = item_score;
            min_item = &item;
            if (item_score == -INFINITY) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return min_item;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question which was not clear enough. I'm sorry but I'd prefer a code snippet which let the code as easy to understand as `std::min_element` is.

Comment: @YSC: I've updated my answer to make it a full-fledged function which at the call site will be even easier to understand than `std::min_element`.  Just say `auto argmin = smallest(items);` and you're done.  Of course, it can be made fully generic taking `score` as a functor and `items` as a template type if you want.

Comment: yeah.. i'm still hoping for some functions from `<algorithm>` to get something similar with less writing (I'm lazy). But if I don't get anything I'll accept your answer although we learn nothing from it (don't take it personally, i'm not questioning your capability, it's just that if this answer is the best one could give, the question itself is meaningless).

Comment: @YSC: I wrote all the code for you, I don't understand how laziness might play a part in it.  For you to now say "we learn nothing" is offensive.

Comment: I'm sorry it is not meant to be. I value your input, really. But if this is the best that can be, my question is worth nothing. About laziness, I'm being metaphoric here: i'm just saying I like my code as succinct as possible.

Comment: @YSC , _if this answer is the best one could give, the question itself is meaningless_  is Controversial! .. , because an answer using  _functions from <algorithm>_  would probably be just writing how to use that function (boring! and meaningless) .. without showing the _technical_ brilliance .. the leverage of this _technical_ answer being a guide to choose, which can't be considered meaningless :)

Comment: @MohammadKanan _meaningless to me_* then^^ I think there is no technical brilliance in finding a minimum in a discrete, finite set. The brilliance could, on the other hand, lie on the simplicity and readability of the code doing so.

Comment: @YSC, perception here is different. the condition you put in the question was the real question  _calling score() multiple times on some items may be worrying_ .. so this beyond iterating a a discrete finite set .. I am saying the question was NOT meaningless  NOR the answer ... knowing that a function from <algorithm> could do it is just an add on :)

Comment: Just for information, I did upvote this answer. I think **this is a perfectly valid answer**. It just is not what I expected and I updated my question _after_ John answered. I'm sorry if I mislead anyone thinking otherwise.

Comment: (Put the check for `-INFINITY` in "the *new `min_item` found*-block". I'm out  of practice regarding const correctness: is that saying *the vector shall not be modified*, without declaring same about each item (but the return value)?)

Comment: @greybeard I agree, `smallest` should return a (non-const) `Item*`.

Comment: @YSC: No, because a `const vector<>&` gives only `const_iterators`, and we are effectively returning a `const Item*` "iterator" into that vector.  If it were `const vector<Item*>&` then yes, we could return non-const `Item*`.

Comment: @john yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

As I commented above, if the vector is not too big, you can use `std::transform` to store all scores first, then apply `std::min_element`.

However, if you want to take benefit of "lazy evaluation", and still want to use C++'s STL, there are some tricks to work it out.

The point is `std::accumulate` can be regarded as a general `reduce` or `fold` operation (like `foldl` in haskell). With C++17's syntax sugar for `std::tuple`, we can write something like:

```
    auto [min_ind, _, min_value] = std::accumulate(items.begin(), items.end(),
        std::make_tuple(-1LU, 0LU, std::numeric_limits<double>::max()),
        [] (std::tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t, double> accu, const Item &s) {
            // up to this point, the index of min, the current index, and the last minimal value
            auto [min_ind, cur_ind, prev_min] = accu;
            double r = score(s);
            if ( r < prev_min ) {
                return std::make_tuple(cur_ind, cur_ind + 1, r);
            } else {
                return std::make_tuple(min_ind, cur_ind + 1, prev_min);
            }
    });
```

Comment: I simultaneously transformed your suggestion into an answer. i'm happy we have different reading. Give me a sec to compare them :)

Comment: It is indeed really close to what I would have written in a functional language as Haskell or OCaml are.